# Center SVG Object on responsive canvas

Tags: svg, responsive, viewport

The SVG canvas is configured to adjust to the browser window and always fill 100% horizontally and vertically.
I want the blue cube to always be in the **bottom center** of the window and also stay the same size.

Is there any way to change the position of the cube or the viewBox, so that the cube always stays in the bottom center no matter what size the browser window has?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>           
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { background:#eee; margin:0 }
    svg {display:block; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff;}
  </style>
</head>
        
<body>
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/> <!--Background--> 
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/> <!--Cube-->
  </svg>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use javascript for this. The `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` will give you the size of the SVG canvas.Alternatively you may use the `getBoundingClientRect()`

```js
let x,y;

function init(){
x = svg.clientWidth/2 - 50;
y = svg.clientHeight - 100;
therect.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x)
therect.setAttributeNS(null,"y",y)
}

setTimeout(function() {
  init();
  addEventListener('resize', init, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
body { background:#eee; margin:0 }
svg {display:block; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/><!--Background--> 
    <rect id="therect" x="50%" y="100%" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/><!--Cube-->
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the viewbox origin to the center with `viewbox="-50 -50 100 100"`,
and from there on draw all the elements taking into account the relative values set by viewbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>           
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { background:#eee; margin:0 }
    svg {display:block; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fff;}
  </style>
</head>
        
<body>
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" >
    <rect x="-50vw" y="-50vw" width="100vw" height="100vw" fill="lightgreen"/> <!--Background--> 
    <rect x="-25" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="blue"/> <!--Cube-->
  </svg>       
</body>
</html>
```

PS:I don't how well `vw` units are supported as svg attributes values so you might want to test that.